# Cannot set Headers on HttpFormUrlEncodedContent

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient.SendRequestAsync and post [HttpFormUrlEncodedContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpformurlencodedcontent.aspx) with some custom headers.

When trying to:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> requestData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
requestData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("form", "content"));
HttpFormUrlEncodedContent request = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(requestData);

request.Headers.TryAppendWithoutValidation("Custom", "Header");
```

I get exception:

> WinRT information: Misused header name. Make sure request headers are
>   used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with
>   HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

How can I add per-request custom headers with HttpFormUrlEncodedContent?

Note, that while I know for HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders, it is not quite an option, because I'd like to reuse the HttpClient instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you cannot actually set Headers to the Content itself. Turns out you need to wrap the HttpFormUrlEncodedContent in [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httprequestmessage.aspx) and then set the headers to the HttpRequestMessage object like this:

```
HttpFormUrlEncodedContent content = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(requestData);
HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ServiceUri);
req.Content = content;
req.Headers.Add("Custom", "Header");
```